# My Form is not showing errors and input values after validation

Tags: django, django-forms, django-templates, django-crispy-forms

My model.py

```
class VehicleInquiry(TimeStampedModel):
    inquiry_status = models.PositiveSmallIntegerField(_("inquiry status"), choices=INQUIRY_STATUS_CHOICES, default=1)
    full_name = models.CharField(_("full name"), max_length=100)
    address = models.CharField(_("address"), max_length=200)
    ---- other fields ----
```

My Crispy form.py:

```
class VehicleInquiryForm(forms.ModelForm):
    --- overridden form fields ---    

class Meta:
    model = VehicleInquiry
    fields = ('full_name', 'email')


def __init__(self, request=None, stock_product=None, *args, **kwargs):
    super(VehicleInquiryForm, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
    self.fields['is_subscribed'].label = _("Keep me updated")
    self.helper = FormHelper()
    self.helper.template_pack = "bootstrap3"
    self.helper.form_method = "post"
    self.helper.form_id = "vehicle-shipping-form"
    self.initial['insurance'] = True
    self.helper.add_input(
        Submit('inquiry', _('Inquiry'), css_class='btn btn-default',)
    )
    self.helper.form_method = 'post'
    self.helper.layout = Layout(
        Fieldset(
        _("1. Choose Your Final Destination"),
        Div(
            Field('country2', css_class="order-select-country"),
        ),
        
            --- other fields ---                   
        )
```

My CBV view.py:

```
class VehicleStockDetailView(TemplateView):
    model = StockProduct
    template_name = "site/product/vehicle-detail.html"
    template_name_done = "site/contact/contact-us-done.html"
    template_name_done_email = "site/contact/emails/contact-us-done.html"
    
    def post(self, request, slug, *args, **kwargs):
        form = VehicleInquiryForm(request.POST)
        ip=""
        if form.is_valid():             
            form.save()
            return render(request, self.template_name_done, {
                'full_name': request.POST['full_name'],
                'email': request.POST['email'],
            })
    
    
        vehicle = get_object_or_404(VehicleStock, slug=slug)
        return render(request, self.template_name, {
            'product': vehicle,
            'form': form
        })
  
    def get(self, request, slug, *args, **kwargs):
        vehicle = get_object_or_404(VehicleStock, slug=slug)
        form = VehicleInquiryForm()
        return render(request, self.template_name, {
            'product': vehicle,
            'form': form
        })
```

The form is loading OK as a GET, but when I click Inquiry as a post request it does not show neither errors nor entered values. In my template I am loading form as {% crispy form %}. Need help.

Comment: Why aren't too using a Form view for this?

Comment: Because I am extending from another view BaseView which used TemplateView. In Base View I am defining meta files. That's why I do not like to change all view to FormView

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You've changed the signature of the form init function so that the first positional arguments are request and `stock_product`. You should avoid doing this - generally I'd recommend using `kwargs` instead, but in this case you should remove them completely as you are **not using those values** in that method.

Also note your code would be simpler if you used a FormView, which takes care of almost all of that logic for you.

Comment: Thank you usually I use stock_product. But to simplify the code, I removed some fields which are not important for the question. Anyway, I will follow your advice and try to use FormView. Thx. I will let the results later.

Comment: As you advised I removed request and stock_product from __init__. Now it works. I use kwrgs from now on. Thx you saved my time, I was stuck in here and read many articles. But it was mostly about FBV or FormView.